# How do I associate a purchased domain name with my Ubuntu nginx Server (already configured)?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, server, dns, registrar

I have set up an nginx server on Ubuntu.
Now the IP address of my machine can also be reached from the outside of my network, navigating to it using a browser, that shows the default nginx page. it works!
Now I wish to buy a domain on one of the many registrars and associate it with my Ubuntu server (hosting) here.. ... how do I have to do this? my IP address changes often and I on't know how to fix it and the steps for associate the prurchased domain name to my IP address...
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a static IP address. If it impossible, you can order Dynamic DNS service like [this](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6147083?hl=en).